# using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported

Tags: podspec, bridging-header

I want to make a pod mixed Objective-C and Swift. And i add

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' =>'$(PODS_ROOT)/../SwiftDemo/SwiftDemo-Bridging-Header.h' }
```

in my `podspec` file。

But there's still one error occured when i verify the `podspec` file:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  <unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

Someone asked this question at  [#7213](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7213), but it has no help for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used

```
s.public_header_files = 'SwiftDemo/TargetA/*.h'
```

and it's working!